# Как просмотреть базу данных приложения?

Tags: android, android-studio

Купил новый телефон и появилась проблема: я не могу просматривать базу данных, так как рутировать телефон — смерть гарантии, а без рута не посмотреть базу данных! После поисков в интернете я так и не нашел внятного ответа на то, как можно просмотреть базу (или даже базы) данных приложения! Как через Android Studio можно открыть базу данных (и проверить, есть ли она вообще)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Базы данных сторонних приложений без рута никак нельзя. Если вам надо посмотреть бд вашего приложения, то можете написать функцию, которая будет копировать вашу бд в общедоступную папку.

Comment: Именно это мне и нужно!

Comment: temq, дайте, пожалуйста, рабочий код функции, про которую Вы написали. Реально это оказалось для меня сложнейшей проблемой.`http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/533801/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bd%d0%b0-sqlite-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b4%d1%8c`