# Скопировать используемую базу данных на SQLite хотя бы куда-нибудь

Tags: android

Второй день не получается выполнить элементарное: скопировать этот неуловимый файл. Вот код:

```
if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "SD-карта не доступна: " + Environment.getExternalStorageState(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "SD-карта доступна: " + Environment.getExternalStorageState(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // получаем путь к SD
                File sdPath = getExternalFilesDir(null);
                // добавляем свой каталог к пути
                sdPath = new File(sdPath.getAbsolutePath());
                // создаем каталог
                if (!sdPath.exists())
                {
                    sdPath.mkdirs();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "создали папку", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                try
                {
                    // открываем потоки для записи
                    File fFrom = new File(this.getDatabasePath("DBtimes.db").getAbsolutePath(), "DBtimes.db");
                    File fTo = new File(sdPath, "CH_" + s_now + ".db");
                    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(fFrom);
                    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fTo);
                    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                    int len;
                    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0)
                    {
                        out.write(buf, 0, len);
                    }
                    // Закрываем потоки
                    in.close();
                    out.close();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            s_now + "копируем файл    ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "не нашли файл", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "другая ошибка", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
```

Что я только не писал здесь:

```
File fFrom = new File(this.getDatabasePath("DBtimes.db").getAbsolutePath(), "DBtimes.db");
```

и

```
File fFrom = new File("/data/data/имя_пакета/databases/DBtimes.db");
```

и просто

```
File(getDatabasePath("DBtimes.db").getAbsolutePath(), "DBtimes.db");
```

и с расширением .db и без, и открытую базу копировать пытался, и закрытую.
Также не получается и так:

```
File fFrom = new File(getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("DBtimes.db").getAbsolutePath(), "DBtimes.db");
```

а

```
Сontext.getDatabasePath("DBtimes.db").getAbsolutePath();
```

Окрашивает в красный цвет слово Сontext или в другом случае пишет, что
 нестатичный getDatabasePath("DBtimes.db") не может применяться со статичным Сontext.
Что же не так?

Comment: А что конкретно не получается? Получить путь к файлу БД или записать его?.. Разрешения на запись/чтение файлов в манифесте прописаны? На какой версии ОС пробуете?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Срабатывает Toast "не нашли файл" из FileNotFoundException. То есть не может взять файл БД. Я по адресу "куда" записывал файлы и копировал - так проверял. А вот взять файл БД не получается. Может, влияет то, что это находится в "@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody") "@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
         switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.export: //экспорт данных", но текстовые файлы из  места внутри папки назначения копирует и с этим.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/459405/17609

Comment: ОС, не 6 версии часом?.. Файл вообще существует в папке? Т.е. в списке файлов папки он есть?

Comment: на 6.0. :)  Этот метод читал и пробовал. Ничего не происходит. Проверку перечня файлов пока не делал, как Вы советовали через массив, потому что не знаю как его выводить на экран.

Comment: Скорее всего дело в версии ОС - с 6 надо запрашивать разрешения в рантайме. Так что если вам разово это сделать надо - то запустите на версии меньше 6. Ну или читайте доки на тему запроса разрешений.

Answer (score 2):

Нашел намного банальнее выход: прямое указание на адрес, но с двумя косыми чертами.

```
 File fFrom = new File("//data/data/имя_пакета/databases/", "DBtimes");
```